# Avoiding excessive memory allocation in golang when using an io.Writer

Tags: memory, go, profiling, heap-memory

I am working on a command line tool in Go called [redis-mass](https://github.com/tlehman/redis-mass) that converts a bunch of redis commands into [redis protocol format](http://redis.io/topics/protocol).

The first step was to port the node.js version, almost literally to Go. I used `ioutil.ReadFile(inputFileName)` to get a string version of the file and then returned an encoded string as output.

When I ran this on a file with 2,000,000 redis commands, it took about 8 seconds, compared to about 16 seconds with the node version. I guessed that the reason it was only twice as fast was because it was reading the whole file into memory first, so I changed my encoding function to accept a pair `(raw io.Reader, enc io.Writer)`, and it looks like this:

```
func EncodeStream(raw io.Reader, enc io.Writer) {
    var args []string
    var length int

    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(raw)

    for scanner.Scan() {
            command := strings.TrimSpace(scanner.Text())
            args = parse(command)
            length = len(args)
            if length > 0 {
                    io.WriteString(enc, fmt.Sprintf("*%d\r\n", length))
                    for _, arg := range args {
                            io.WriteString(enc, fmt.Sprintf("$%d\r\n%s\r\n", len(arg), arg))
                    }
            }
    }
}
```

However, this took 12 seconds on the 2 million line file, so I used github.com/pkg/profile to see how it was using memory, and it looks like the number of memory allocations is huge:

```
# Alloc = 3162912
# TotalAlloc = 1248612816
# Mallocs = 46001048
# HeapAlloc = 3162912
```

Can I constrain the `io.Writer` to use a fixed sized buffer and avoid all those allocations?

More generally, how can I avoid excessive allocations in this method? [Here's the full source for more context](https://github.com/tlehman/redis-mass/blob/master/redis_protocol.go)

Comment: io.Writer doesn't have a buffer, it's an interface. In your code, why are you buffering a buffer?

Comment: Who said all your allocs are in the `io.Writer`? What do you think `command := strings.TrimSpace(scanner.Text())` does? I think it's responsible for about 2 million allocs.

Comment: `fmt.Sprintf` causes a lot of allocs too.

Comment: Right, I am not asking the right question, also, good catch, I've unbuffered my bytes.Buffer, in newest master

Comment: @evanmcdonnal it was a guess, I am thinking JimB is on to something too

Comment: It's useful to avoid string manipulation if you want to reduce allocations. Use and reuse []byte slices as much as possible.

Answer (score 1):

Reduce allocations by working with []byte instead of strings. fmt.Printf directly to the output instead of fmt.Sprintf and io.WriteString.

```
func EncodeStream(raw io.Reader, enc io.Writer) {
    var args []string
    var length int

    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(raw)

    for scanner.Scan() {
            command := bytes.TrimSpace(scanner.Bytes())
            args = parse(command)
            length = len(args)
            if length > 0 {
                    fmt.Printf(enc, "*%d\r\n", length))
                    for _, arg := range args {
                           fmt.Printf(enc, "$%d\r\n%s\r\n", len(arg), arg))
                    }
            }
    }
}
```